# Using OpenCV2.3 and MFC with VS 2008 on Windows 7 - .exe process won't end

Tags: windows-7, mfc, opencv

I'm trying to debug my program (an iterative process of "did that work? No? How about this?") and everytime it crashes during runtime (because 2 dimensional pointers confuse me) and I try to run  it (after making a change) I get a LNK1168 error (cannot write since *.exe is open).

So I open up task manager, find the process and hit end process.  But it doesn't end and I can't run my program again until it goes away seemingly at random.

How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a thread still hanging around. Instead of closing it through procman, do shift-F5 in the VS debugger to stop it. That will kill all processes and threads cold.